# Shell script to parse ip:port from a text file

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, parsing

I get daily a text file with ip:port, one per line, example:

```
11.22.33.44:80
22.33.44.55:8080
33.44.55.66:7777
```

I would like to parse the first ip and port in two different variables, then write them into another file, wait execution of a program that use these variables, loop this cycle to pass all the `ip:port` to the file and execute program.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line junk
do 
  addr=${line%%:*}
  port=${line##*:}
  ./nuke $addr $port
  retval=$?
  case retval in
    0) echo "$addr $port nuked" >> nuke.log ;;
    *) echo "$addr $port avoid nuke" >> nuke.log ;;
  esac

done < /some/file/with/ipports
```

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428579/shell-script-to-parse-ipport-from-a-text-file , going anyway to check your solution to learn

Comment: rewrite solution to meet all your conditions :)